# My RecyclerView is not populated by submitList

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently working on a fragment that contains a recyclerView, and I'm attempting to populate it with data obtained from an API. However, I've run into some issues as the recyclerView doesn't seem to display any data even though I've verified that the results aren't null.

The Fragment:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeFragmentBinding binding = HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater);

        tabLayout = binding.tabLayout;
        rvProducts = binding.rvProducts;

        setupRecyclerView();

        viewModel.getAllProducts();

        viewModel.products.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), products -> {
            Log.d("HSV", products.toString());
            productsAdapter.submitList(products);
        });

        return HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater).getRoot();
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter();
        rvProducts.setAdapter(productsAdapter);
        rvProducts.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2));
    }
```

The ListAdapter:

```
public class ProductsAdapter extends ListAdapter<Product, ProductsAdapter.ProductsViewHolder> {

    public ProductsAdapter() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false);

        return new ProductsViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product item = getItem(position);
        holder.bind(item);
    }

    static class ProductsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final ItemProductBinding binding;

        public ProductsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            binding = ItemProductBinding.bind(itemView);
        }

        void bind(Product itemProduct) {

            binding.txtNameProduct.setText(itemProduct.getTitle());
            binding.txtTypeProduct.setText(itemProduct.getCategory());
            binding.txtPriceProduct.setText(itemProduct.getPrice());
        }
    }

    public static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product> DIFF_CALLBACK  = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Product oldItem, @NonNull Product newItem) {
            return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Product oldItem, @NonNull Product newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }
    };
}
```

I have previous experience in developing Android apps using Kotlin, and I'm currently learning Java as well. My assumption was that populating a RecyclerView would be accomplished in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

You've set up one `RecyclerView` and returned a different one:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ## Creating binding object on which set up is done ##
        HomeFragmentBinding binding = HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater);

        tabLayout = binding.tabLayout;
        rvProducts = binding.rvProducts;

        setupRecyclerView();

        viewModel.getAllProducts();

        viewModel.products.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), products -> {
            Log.d("HSV", products.toString());
            productsAdapter.submitList(products);
        });

        // ## Creating new binding object View on which no set up is done #
        return HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater).getRoot();
    }
```

Replace

```
return HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater).getRoot();
```

With

```
return binding.getRoot();
```

Comment: Great, that solved the problem! I really appreciate your assistance, it saved me a significant amount of time. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If your question is answered, you can mark the answer as accepted.